# MediaRecorder causing IllegalStateException

Tags: android, resources, illegalstateexception

This only happens when a user presses the back button and re-enters the intent. I think the issue is I have a file that starts a MediaRecorder to grab sound, but when the user backs out the MediaRecorder isn't closing or I have a runOnUiThread that might not be closing either when the back button is pressed?

I have the following code which I thought would work:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    try {
        stop();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void stop() throws IOException {
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }
}
```

The whole class this is in I have in a `runOnUiThread` block, in

```
private class CustomSense extends TimerTask {
    private String amps;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                amps = String.valueOf(sounder.getAmplitude());
                soundDisplay.setText(amps);
            }
        });
    }

    public String getAmps() {
        return amps;
    }
}
```

But maybe I don't quite understand how onBack works or runOnUiThread? I've been going over the documentation for both of those and MediaRecorder so I could easily be missing something in there (note this does not occur when going into another intent and back through, only when pressing the back button and re-starting the intent)

I feel like the issue is I'm not closing either when the back button is pressed and it's trying to run two instances of them causing the IllegalStateException, but I can't figure out how to actually close them when a user presses their phone's back button.

The StackTrace is as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: PID: 28671
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{SensorDisplayActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2671)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2736)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6154)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
                                                                     at SoundDetect.start(SoundDetect.java:62)
                                                                     at SoundDetect.<init>(SoundDetect.java:82)
                                                                     at SensorDisplayActivity.onCreate(SensorDisplayActivity.java:89)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6683)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2624)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2736) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6154) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

SoundDetect: 62 is mRecorder.start() in

```
 public void start() throws IOException {
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/null.3gp";

            if (mRecorder == null) {
                mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
                mRecorder.prepare();
                mRecorder.start();
            }
}
```

SoundDetect 82 is just a .start() call

Comment: So turns out I needed to call 'stop()' in my 'onPause()' during a display activity, not my microphone activity's 'onBackPressed()'

Comment: But now it crashes on the first run of the app and I have to reopen it